# Detecting tunnels with Core Location

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I am using Core Location for turn by turn based navigation and would like to show a "GPS lost" alert in tunnels.

The problem is that the following two scenarios look the same to the app:

- The user drives into a tunnel. GPS updates cease because there is no way to know where the user is.
- The user stops at an intersection. GPS updates cease because the user is no longer moving.

**I need to set these two situations apart. Ideas?**

I have tried looking at the `horizontalAccuracy` property, but sometimes the updates cease completely, so there is no new `horizontalAccuracy` information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally with CLLocationManager set for best accuracy for navigation and no distance filter, you should get a location update once a second even if you are stopped at an intersection.

If you stop getting those updates while the motion coprocessor (using `CMMotionActivityManager`) says you are still driving then you can infer that you are in a tunnel (or underground car park or someplace with a bad GPS signal).

BTW, GPS updates should not stop when you are stopped at an intersection if you have set `distanceFilter = 0` and `desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` and `activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation`, etc.

Another thing to watch out for, if the tunnel has cellular coverage, you may still get location update from cellular triangulation but with worse accuracy.  If the `CLLocation.horizontalAccuracy` goes from less than 50m to over 300m then you have lost GPS/GLONASS coverage even though you are still getting location updates.

Comment: This works well enough, we continue to get updates from time to time inside tunnels with very bad accuracy values. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Look at [locationManager:didFailWithError:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didFailWithError:) method:

> If the location service is unable to retrieve a location right away,
>   it reports a kCLErrorLocationUnknown error and keeps trying.

To determine a second situation (user stops) use [locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates:) method:

> When the location manager detects that the device’s location is not
>   changing, it can pause the delivery of updates in order to shut down
>   the appropriate hardware and save power. When it does this, it calls
>   this method to let your app know that this has happened.

Comment: Thanks, any idea what will happen if it's able to retrieve a location right away, but fails later?

Comment: When location manager fails to retrieve location it will call this method. When it will be able to retrieve location again it will call `locationManager:didUpdateLocations: `

Comment: These methods are well documented, so it might be a bug if real behavior is different. Are you sure that locationManager:didFailWithError: isn't called when location is not determined (like in the tunnel) or locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates: isn't called when user stops moving?

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work. While driving in a tunnel for a couple minutes, `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` is initially not called at all, then `locationManager:didFailWithError:` gets called **sometimes**, and then `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` is called again inside the tunnel at random.

Comment: And what about second method?

Comment: My next idea is to add a flag `userStopped`, set it to YES in `locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates:` and to NO in `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`. Then check `locationManager.location.timestamp`. If last location was retrieved long ago and `userStopped` is NO, show your "GPS lost" alert.

Comment: CLLocationManager will only report an error if it fails because of a permission denied or if it can't get any signals (GPS, GLONASS, cellular, WiFi) at all for a long time (like 60 seconds).  IMHO this method is probably not going to help.

Comment: Yes, Maciej already wrote that this method was not helpful in his problem with tunnels. Thanks for explanation anyway.